# How to check realtime server statistics and health - Laravel / PHP

Tags: php, laravel, server, laravel-5, newrelic

Basically i would like to have some kind of server statistics on my dashboard. Is there any package out there that does this out of the box.

I know finding the health of the server is pretty simple, by checking the status code for 200. But what about other stats? Stats like, no of db queries, load on the server & db, no of visitors on the site right now etc. I know most of them are pretty simple, but is there any way of getting this information in realtime without slowing down the server.

Can we benifit from services like NewRelic Lite. We could use the api to get the information from NewRelic and just display them on the dashboard.  Will that be a good idea?

**EDIT:**
I am also looking into [nagios](https://www.nagios.org), which looks like an opensource alternative to NewRelic.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it [Laravel Server monitor](https://github.com/ericmakesstuff/laravel-server-monitor/blob/master/README.md) could help you. I've never used but it could give you some "light".

New relic seems to be a very complex and complete service, you could benefit from it a lot. Display every type of information that they can give you, its basically one of the most complete services i've seem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out  "laravel server monitor", I did came across it but seemed very basic. I am still looking into NewRelic, and looks like they have a very good reputation.

Comment: Good to know, its something to use on my future projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think `antonioribeiro/tracker` is the best, [Here](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) is the link to the repo.

I have used it in many projects, Its well maintained and well updated. Good Luck.